# Twitter Churn Rate

Tags: data-request, twitter

I need the monthly churn rate for twitter. How do I get the number of annual users from  the number of Monthly Active Users for a social media site? Is there some general formula or some percentage that is used? I am guessing the churn rate would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Monthly Active Users for any user based company in their SEC filings. For twitter was owned by Twitter, Inc.(Now X Corp.), you can see Monthly Active Users and other parameters in [**their 10-Q filings**](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=custom&ciks=0001418091&entityName=TWITTER%252C%2520INC.%2520(CIK%25200001418091)&startdt=2007-07-01&enddt=2023-07-26&filter_forms=10-Q).